# Zend_GData Spreadsheet - Invalid query parameter value for grid-id

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-sheets, zend-gdata

I am trying to update a google spreadsheet through Zend_GData library. I am sure the user ID and password is correct. I think the issue is with spreadsheet key or worksheet ID. Even I don't know exactly how to get this worksheetID. Kindly help me on this. This is the exact URL to m worksheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmW1-CVeX7oOdGRkYURWNXVMRi1DTW9NTGNhZ09OTGc&hl=en_US#gid=0

Here is my code.

```
$user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
$spreadsheetKey = "0AmW1-CVeX7oOdGRkYURWNXVMRi1DTW9NTGNhZ09OTGc";
$worksheetId = "Sheet1";
try
{           
    $spreadsheetService->insertRow(array('Prasad','10000'),$spreadsheetKey,$worksheetId);

}
catch(Exception $error)
{

    echo $error->getMessage() ;

}
```

And this is the error message I see on my browser screen.

Expected response code 200, got 400 Invalid query parameter value for grid-id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I could find the SpreadsheetKey and WorkSheetID by using bellow code.

```
$user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$service            = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client             = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
$feed               = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
$sheetName = "Test1";
foreach($feed->entries as $entry)
{               
    if($entry->title->text == $sheetName)
    {
        $spreadsheetURL = $entry->id;
        break;
    }
}

$spreadsheetKey = basename($spreadsheetURL);

$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
$feed = $spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query); 

echo "Spreadskeet Key : $spreadsheetKey <br/>";

foreach($feed->entries as $entry)
{
    echo "ID of sheet {$entry->title->text} is " . basename($entry->id) . " <br/>";
}
```

Once I got those values also my script didn't work. Then I found that when we define the array the 'Key's should mentioned in lower case with no spaces.

```
$spreadsheetService->insertRow(array('name'=>'Prasad','value'=>'10000'),$spreadsheetKey,$worksheetId);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer.  Helped me a ton.

Comment: Good luck... Happy to hear it was useful.

Comment: This is still the best solution to get started with Zend Framework minimal as any other beginners guide is simply overcomplicated. Thank you for this script!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code also, tested and worked for me

```
<?php
// load Zend Gdata libraries
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
try {  
  // connect to API
  $service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
  $service = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);

  // get list of available spreadsheets
  $feed = $service->getSpreadsheetFeed();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
foreach($feed->entries as $entry) {
    $spreadsheetURL = $entry->id;
}
$spreadsheetKey = basename($spreadsheetURL);
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
$feed = $service->getWorksheetFeed($query);
echo "Spreadsheet Key: <strong>$spreadsheetKey</strong> <br>";
foreach($feed as $entry) {
    $sName = $entry->title->text;
    echo "ID of sheet $sName is: <strong>".basename($entry->id)."</strong><br>";
}
?>
```